# Why is the norm of a matrix-vector product less than or equal to the product of the matrix and vector norms?

Tags: matrices, matrix-norms

In a textbook, I came across matrix norms induced from vector norms, and it says:

$$
||A x|| \le ||A||\cdot||x|| 
$$
$A \in \mathbb{R}^{NxN},\ x \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

May I please ask for a gentle proof on why is this the case?

Comment: By definition, the norm of $A$ is the smallest number making this works for all $x$.

Comment: @MartinR The textbook says this equation is valid for any matrix norm induced from a vector norm, without restricting to a specific norms (such as 1-norm 2-norm, frob-norm, inf-norm).

Comment: I had missed the *“induced from vector norms”* in your question, sorry about that. But then the inequality follows immediately from the definition of induced matrix norms.

Comment: @MartinR Yes. I guessed that it must be relatively straightforward for those with an appropriate mathematical background (which is perhaps why no explanation was given in the textbook). I shall much appreciate that elaborate on this as an answer, and I shall be glad to accept it?